# jtwig : Ignore incorrect variables / function

Tags: java, twig, jtwig

I've recently searched a lot about this subject but I cannot figure how to do it : I just want to configure jtwig in a way that when it encounters an unknown function or variable, it simply ignores it.

For example, if jtwig parse this :

```
{{ varA }}
{{ varB }}
```

With varA = 2, I get the following output :

```
2
{{ varB }}
```

Thanks for your answers and sorry for my bad english.

PS : I don't want to put varB = {{ varB }}.

Answer (score 2):

**1. To ignore always**

The "[verbatim](http://www.jtwig.org/documentation/reference/tags/other-tags)" tag can be used.
Jtwig will not try to parse the content within this tag.

```
{{ varA }}
{% verbatim %}
{{ varB }}
{% endverbatim %}
```

Output

```
2
{{ varB }}
```

---

**2. To ignore if empty**

You could use [Control Flows](http://www.jtwig.org/documentation/reference/tags/control-flow) and [Functions](http://jtwig.org/documentation/reference/functions) to check if a variable exists or not and then use verbatim tag. This is a workaround. I would also like to see if there is a cleaner way to do this in jtwig.

```
{% if (empty(varB)) %}
    {% verbatim %}{{varB}}{% endverbatim %}
{% else %}
    {{varB}}
{% endif %}
```

Output

```
{{varB}}
```

---

**3. Default Value if NULL or UNDEFINED**

Use the [default](http://www.jtwig.org/documentation/reference/functions#default) value, if the variable is either NULL or UNDEFINED

```
{{ default(varB, '{{varB}}') }}
```

Output

```
{{varB}}
```

---